# Installing Two PHP version in Centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I need to run two PHP version in my centos 7 server. I am currently using PHP Webstatic repo for installing PHP and using apache. I just gone through the internet and most of them are using Remi repo for PHP installation. I don't want Remi instead I need to install PHP from Webstatic. Is it really possible. suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Which needed versions ?

Comment: PHP 5.6 and 70 will be good

Answer (score 2):

> I need to install PHP from Webstatic.

But why ?

Sorry, but it seems **webtatic** is a dead project (no change since [Oct 2019](https://github.com/webtatic-rpms)) and latest version is 7.2.24 (latest being 7.2.32, no 7.3 and no 7.4) so I will heartily recommend to avoid it.

> I need to run two PHP version in my centos 7 server.

Installation of various versions simultaneously is possible using Sofware Collections (SCL), designed for this.

This is described in [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

- [CentOS SCL](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) official repository provides SCLs for PHP 7.2 (until Nov 2020) and 7.3 (until Dec 2021)
- [Remi repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) provides SCLs for PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 and 8.0

Other solution is to run each version in a container (docker, podman...)

P.S. As you want **5.x** and **7.x**, remi is the only repository providing these versions, with security fixes backported for EOLed versions.

Comment: Thankyou..No issues only I need to run PHP5.6 and 7.0 so I guess it is enough to go with PHP webstatic..what did you say?

Comment: again webtatic is a DEAD thing, and don't provides SCL.

Comment: In short, only remi provides SCL of the versions you need, including security backports for EOL versions

Comment: webtatic builds weren't even very good when they were an active project. Remi has always had the highest quality PHP builds. (And other packages too.) Which I suppose is part of the reason Red Hat hired him :)

Comment: @Michael Hampton..Thankyou very much for your inputs..let me try with Remi

Comment: @RemiCollet I have installed remi repo on `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`, but still I can not find php 7.x versions.

Comment: @ChamindaBandara follow the Wizard instructions: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/